# crystal reports Summarizing text field based on Group

Tags: crystal-reports

I've a set of data which has 3 columns as Product Name, Quantity and Narration. and I've grouped the records based on Product Name. So I can easily get the Product Name and Total Quantity. But issue is when have to get the Summery of Narration Field.
I've arranged the field name in the Group Footer. I tried a formula like

Example:

```
Product Name Quantity Narration
A            50       'Narr1'
A            100      'Narr2'
B            50       'Narr3'
```

Result:

```
A,150,'Narr1,Narr2'   --> Correct
B,50,'Narr1,Narr2,Narr3'  --- Wrong
```

Please help.

Comment: What exactly is the Narration? Can you give us some data examples?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a manual, running-total field:

**{table.product_name} header**

```
//{@reset}

// third pass
WhilePrintingRecords;

// empty array
Stringvar Array reset;

// reset values array
Stringvar Array values := reset;
```

**details**

```
// {@increment}

// third pass
WhilePrintingRecords;

// declare
Stringvar Array values;

// increase array's size by one position
Redim Preserve values[Ubound(values)+1];

// store value in new, empty position
values[Ubound(values)] := {table.narration};
```

**{table.product_name} footer**

```
//{@display}

// third pass
WhilePrintingRecords;

// declare
Stringvar Array value;

// join
Join(values, ",");
```